# How to set autoincrement Ids in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design

I'm facing the following scenario:

The IDs of my entities are auto incremented, so I set the setter of all of them to `private`, but when I want to make a unit test for my domain class I found myself needing to get and set the ID.

How do I go about setting the ID?

```
public WorkingTime(string name, short numberOfHours, short numberOfShortDays, int workingGroupId)
{
    Name = name;
    NumberOfHours = numberOfHours;
    NumberOfShortDays = numberOfShortDays;
    WorkingGroupId = workingGroupId;
    ActivatedWorkingTimes = new List<WorkingTimeActivation>();
}

private ICollection<WorkingTimeActivation> _activatedWorkingTimes;

public int Id { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public short NumberOfHours { get; set; }
public short NumberOfShortDays { get; set; }
public int WorkingGroupId { get; set; }
public virtual WorkingGroup WorkingGroup { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<WorkingTimeActivation> ActivatedWorkingTimes { get => _activatedWorkingTimes; set => _activatedWorkingTimes = value; }
```

---

**Test example:**

```
var workingGroup = new WorkingGroup("WG", 3, Week.Sunday, 2);
workingGroup.AssignedWorkingTimes.Add(new WorkingTime("Winter", 8, 1, 1));
workingGroup.AssignedWorkingTimes.Add(new WorkingTime("Summer", 6, 0, 1));
```

Now I want to set `workingGroupId`

> Should I use public setter instead ?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to set the ID in your unit test?

Comment: @mjwills to make a relationship with other entities, in this example there's a relationship between (`WorkingGroup & WorkingTime`) and in the constructor of `WorkingTime` I have to provide the `WorkingGroupId`

Comment: No, `AssignedWorkingTimes.Add` is enough to establish the relationship. Moreover, `workingGroup` doesn't even have its generated ID at that point.

Comment: @GertArnold : but `WorkingTime` constructor need the `WorkingGroupId`

Comment: @GertArnold Should I edit that constructor so passing `WorkingGroup` instead of the `WorkingGroupId` ?

Comment: No, just remove the parameter. `WorkingTime` doesn't need to know its `WorkingGroup` to establish the relationship.

Comment: @GertArnold then Should I remove all primary keys and foreign keys from the constructors ?

Comment: This is the only case I see. Here: yes.

Comment: @GertArnold Could I ask what if it's required to specify the relational entity during the entity creation (in the constructor) in this case should I pass The entity itself instead of its id to overcome this problem ?

Comment: If you have other cases, the code will necessarily be different. You can set Ids, you can set references (`WorkingGroup`), you can add to collections (this case). They'll all do to set relationships.

Comment: @GertArnold : U mean that in these cases i need to make these Ids public setters

Comment: **!!!Don't leak infrastructure concerns into your domain!!!** The problem with this "unit test" should make you **VERY OBVIOUS** that you have dependencies on your infrastructure (database) and persistence knowledge leaks into your domain. An absolute no-go. You should go back at the scratch board and really thing about your domain, design the models **without** persistence in mind. Once your domain and domain logic is complete, start to implement persistence. Not the other way around, since thats not DDD anymore

Comment: @Tseng : Thanks a lot, but how to handle a case like this, I want to use Ids but they are auto increment so I set their setters as private and stuck in unit test! I'll be grateful If you explain more in a full answer.

Comment: Persistence models **are not** domain models. Persistence models are used for ORM Libraries to map to a database. Your domain models have to be persistence ignorant. ORM and DDD don't work well, since ORMs have constraints. You can have entities with an entity id, but this is not necessary the same as primary key on a database. For example when you have an Order, you get an OrderID as entity id, but the primary key may be an incremented number. This one doesn't appear in your domain model, since its **not** related to your domain.

Comment: In DDD you have aggregate roots which are an transaction boundary and everything happens via the aggregate root (i.e. changing its state). For example `Order` and `OrderPosition`. `OrderPosition` per se is not an entity, as it doesn't have an identity. A single `OrderPosition` is meaningless in the context of the domain w/o the order it belongs to. The `Order` would be the aggregate root with maybe `OrderNumber` as it's entity (i.e. ORD12345), where as when you implement this with relational DB you may have an OrderID on the database for relationships, but there is no such field in your domain

Comment: Is the question answered in comments or in the answers section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I use public setter instead ?

Probably not, no.

There are two alternatives to consider.

One is that, if the identifier is really private data, then the test shouldn't need to interact with it directly.  We limit the scope of the test to the *observable* side effects in the model, so that we have the freedom to later change the private implementation details.

Another is that the test is trying to draw your attention to the fact that there are different *strategies* that you might use for generating the identifier, and that a different strategy might be appropriate in different contexts -- one strategy in use in production code, another for use in the test harness.

The basic pattern isolates the strategy and provides the affordances you need to control which strategy is applied.  In the test, we implement the strategy contract using a [test double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html), which allows the *test* to maintain deterministic control over what would otherwise be an arbitrary side effect.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are wanting to keep your entities in the domain layer "pure" by creating the private setter. This is a good thing. One way I've handled tests or the mapping of DTOs to entities is by creating an extension method that gives access to the private setter.

This method uses Marc Gravell's [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) library:

```
using FastMember;
...

public static class DomainExtensions
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, TypeAccessor> _accessors = new Dictionary<Type, TypeAccessor>();

    public static T With<T, TFieldOrProperty>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, TFieldOrProperty>> fieldOrProperty, TFieldOrProperty value)
        where T : class
    {
        if (instance == null)
            return null;

        if (!(fieldOrProperty.Body is MemberExpression member))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{fieldOrProperty}' is not for a property or field.");

        try
        {
            if (!_accessors.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var ta))
                lock (_accessors)
                    ta = _accessors[typeof(T)] = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T), true);

            if (ta[instance, member.Member.Name] != null)
            {
                ta[instance, member.Member.Name] = value;
                return instance;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        // fallback to reflection
        var fi = member.Member as FieldInfo;
        fi?.SetValue(instance, value);
        var pi = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        pi?.SetValue(instance, value);
        return instance;
    }
```

Then you use it like this:

```
workingGroup.With(wg => wg.WorkingGroupId, 2);
```

In this way your entity stays pure. Now you may say, "well I can now bypass the read-only nature of the entity." That's true, but the developer would have to *explicitly* and mindfully violate this access by calling `With()`.

If test cases are the only place you need this access then put the `With()` method in the assembly with your tests. This guarantees your production code can't set the ID.

Answer (score 1):

If `Id` needs to remain private to the class library and also needs to be tested via the testing project, in my opinion, this is the next best option when using C#:

Change the `private set;` to be an `internal set;` or create an internal method for setting the Id.

```
public int Id { get; internal set; }
```

In your class library that has the class that needs to be tested, in solution explorer, under Properties, in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, add the following line:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestingAssembly")]
```

This will make the Internals in your class library that needs to be tested visible to the testing project *only*.  This won't solve the issue of encapsulating `Id` from other code inside the class library but it will keep the internal concern of `Id` from being visible to other DLLs that are not testing the class library.